# Motion analysis, taking in account history

Tags: data-mining, prediction, panel-data, signal-processing

In what branch of statistics should I look into in order to extract value from  motion data?
Are there any models that can take up position history in order to interpolate or extrapolate future routes?
Take the case of ship's; if they are transporting oil and always follow a similar route, how can take that into account for future predictions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spatio-temporal data analysis deals with the problem of motion data. I still don't know if statistical methods apply but data mining approachs exist for the problem.

Thks anyone.

Answer (score 1):

If you have some measurements (e.g. acceleration, radial speed, magnetometer reading) that provide evidence for the states that you don't observe directly (e.g. orientation in same reference frame), take a look at Kalman filter and Complementary filter. This is the example of altitude computation for Inertial Measurement Units in drones for example.
The math is bit frightening but the framework is very powerful.

Comment: I don't have any of those features, +1 for bringing up kalman filter tough I've found it useless as it doesn't model non linear movements (dead reckoning can do the same), and my gps coords are accurate enough.
You may bring up EKF or UKF for non linearity but I haven't had much luck with them in this particular problem.
Also none of those take advantage from position history at a global scale, just locally.

Comment: @Ramalho I would kindly disagree about position history. It actually models the whole history. At time moment $t$ the measurements and state predictions are taken into account from the moment $t-1$. But that $t-1$ made use of $t-2$ and so on.

Comment: Ok, what I mean is: if a ship usually takes a course that information won't be taken into consideration if the ship is traversing the same course in another week, only a time window of the last few position are taken into account. The method wasn't made for what I need.
Overall kalman filter just smoothens the position history.

Comment: @Ramalho Thanks for clarifying! Yes, you are right, Kalman filter just smoothens the position history taking previous measurements and states.